# how to include/require a connection to mysql file from another server with php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a connection file

file name   **inc.server.php**

```
    <?php

function db_name() { return 'dbname'; }
function db_user() { return 'username'; }
function db_pass() { return 'pw'; }
 $koneknodatabase = mysqli_connect('localhost:2020',db_user(),db_pass(),db_name());
function close_Con() {
 mysqli_close(mysqli_connect('localhost:2020',db_user(),db_pass(),db_name()));
}
?>
```

this file save in the my server with IP : 10.2.60.2

but when i require that file from my local pc

with

```
require('http://10.2.60.2/inc.server.php');
global $koneknodatabase;
$select = mysqli_query($koneknodatabase,"select from data");
$data  = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
```

iam run that script on my localhost
but the result is

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
```

i have change allow_url_include to ON from php.ini
please help

Comment: You can't require a PHP script over the network. When you access a `.php` file through a webserver, it executes the script and returns the output, it doesn't return the source code that `require` needs.

Comment: You need to copy the script to your local PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the source code of a PHP script of a remote host like that, otherwise everyone would open the `config.php` file from every webpage they know (and they know the file exists) and get any login data they want.

When you open the URL `http://10.2.60.2/inc.server.php` in your browser you see the content someone outside of the host "10.2.60.2" will see. It will be most likely an empty page since your `inc.server.php` file doesn't generate any output (and shouldn't). So your other PHP host will include just an empty file from his point of view, which means there aren't any functions like `db_name()` defined or any variables like `$koneknodatabase`.

There are different ways on how separated hosts can communicate to each other, but thats a different topic and might result in different questions. Luckily there are millions of informations out there about how two hosts can communicate with each other.